# Examples of coloring algorithms

Tags: coloring

I searched for graph coloring algorithms in google, but couldnt find some examples. In wiki page they have given the names of some algorithms but they haven't given step by step procedures.

Please tell me some source or place where I can find a list of graph coloring algorithms with procedure.

If you know some (preferably simple) algorithms please share it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can find one or two coloring algorithm(s) in chapter 5 , in Introduction to Graph Theory, by Douglas b. West. this chapter is about coloring.

i found this page very useful too.

http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~maheshwa/courses/5703COMP/14Seminars/GraphColorings-report.pdf

also you can find some of best Planar Graph coloring algorithms in Artificial Intelligence , in mit open courseware, lecture 8. Constraints- Search, Domain Reduction.

and there is a book called Graphs, Colourings and the Four-colour Theorom.

hope they are useful